# vs code deploy python project to azure service encounter the error:libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code

I had deploy a python project to azure app service, when I browse the app service, I get the below error message:

```
  Ok     2023-08-26T17:33:18.8719056   import hnswlib
  Error  2023-08-26T17:33:18.8719109   ImportError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  Ok     2023-08-26T17:33:18.8719163   
 Warning 2023-08-26T17:33:18.8719214   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

screenshot:

[image]

I google the issue and try to use the solution: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/497#issuecomment-540830721
add the below script before `import *` in `app.py`

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call
import os
check_call(['apt-get', 'update'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)
check_call(['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'libgl1'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)
check_call(['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'libglib2.0-0'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)
check_call(['apt-get', 'update'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)
```

but is not working, still the same error.

[image]

Comment: The apt module you need to install is `libgomp1`.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, let me try and update you result later

Comment: @Tim, I had modify the module to 'libgomp1', VS code deploy the python project to Azure app service failed. I do not found the error message.The script: from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call
import os
check_call(['apt-get', 'update'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)
check_call(['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'libgomp1'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)
check_call(['apt-get', 'update'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)

Comment: Can you provide complete steps to reproduce?  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JialeDu, I follow the steps to deploy it to azure app service:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli